# get the checked item of Bootstrap dropdown checkboxlist checked value in asp.net using c#

Tags: c#, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a website in which i need to represent many items in dropdownlist with checkboxs.
for that i m using bootstrap dropdown checkbox list as :

```
    <head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <!-- Include Twitter Bootstrap and jQuery: -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-3.0.0.min.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/prettify.css" type="text/css" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/prettify.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>

            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlItems" multiple="multiple" runat="server">
                <asp:ListItem value="cheese">Cheese</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem value="tomatoes">Tomatoes</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem value="mozarella">Mozzarella</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem value="mushrooms">Mushrooms</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem value="pepperoni">Pepperoni</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem value="onions">Onions</asp:ListItem>

            </asp:DropDownList>

            <asp:Button ID="sub" runat="server" OnClick="sub_Click" Text="submit" />
        </div>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#ddlItems').multiselect({
            buttonClass: 'btn btn-default btn-sm'
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Now i have to get the all checked item on button click.
for that i m trying but i didn't get the items..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this is helpfull to you. to select multiple options with Checkboxes in dropdownlist. 
    
       jQuery select multiple options with Checkboxes in dropdownlist
       
       
          
       
       
    
    
    
      
      
      Cheese
      Tomatoes
      Mozzarella
      Mushrooms
      Pepperoni
      Onions

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$('#chkveg').multiselect({
includeSelectAllOption: true
});
$('#btnget').click(function() {
 alert($('#chkveg').val());})
});
</script>
</div>
</form>
</body>
```

and you will get output like this:

[image: jQuery multi select dropdown with0 checkboxes]

Answer (score 2):

You can use this method for that...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$('#chkveg').multiselect({
includeSelectAllOption: true
});
$('#btnget').click(function() {
 alert($('#chkveg').val());})
});
</script>
```